Can users SSH into a device that is connected to a VPN?
I am attempting to set up a small bit torrent server to help keep some necessary files online. The only issue is that I would prefer if users did not know my address.
Similarly, I would be immensely grateful if I could SSH into the device from my other machine.
If I run a VPN client (wiregard, etc.) can I still SSH into it? Or would it block incoming SSH connections? I will be utilizing Debian.
Thank you so much for any help you can provide.

Often it will not "block" anything. It's just that if it uses the the vpn tunnel as its default route, responses for (non-local) hosts that accessing this host NOT via the VPN will be "erroneously" routed into the tunnel, which causes their recipient not receiving or not recognizing them as responses, until / unless you configure policy routing on the host for those responses. (In other words, "OOTB" you would experience problem like being able to SSH into it if you are "in LAN", but not "from the Internet".)

The answer is "it depends".
It depends on the technology.  It depends on the VPN server config.  It depends on what the client supports... "it depends".
Now I run my own VPN server on my home router and I have a couple of internet hosted virtual machines connect via VPN, so those internet servers can see my internal machines.  Because of my config this does not prevent external access to the servers, so "ssh" and "https" to the internet hosted machine still works.
But if I connect my work laptop to my work VPN then it blocks this type of access, because that's what the VPN server tells the VPN client to do.
So, sure; you can have your client connected to a VPN for anonomization and still allow direct ssh into the client... if the VPN client and server allows it!
